# Go: create a mysql table with dash in it ("EDC-3Islvuo")

Tags: mysql, go

I'm trying to make a table with Go and the "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" driver package and want to makes tables from the IDs that are preconfigured (like `rte-432343`). It throws an error when there is a dash in the name. Is there a way around the error: `Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-432343'`

```
request := "CREATE TABLE " + *tablename + " ( dbid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name text, PRIMARY KEY (dbid)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"
_, err := db.Exec(request)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error creating database table", *tablename, err)
}
```

Comment: Wrap the table name with backticks: `request := "CREATE TABLE \`" + *tablename + "\` (`  ...

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I've been thinking I had to escape the backticks with a backslash for that to work.